# How to use calc() inside another function

Tags: css, transform, css-calc

Is it possible to use `calc()` inside of a CSS function like `transform` or `translate`?
I cannot seem to get it working. Here is a demo so you guys can play around:

http://jsfiddle.net/qdJwY/1/

Comment: I don't think translations take percentages. It does work if you use pixels instead of percent but I guess that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: yes but thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `calc()` wherever you can use a length based value in CSS. The example you have provided does work, but actually adds up to 0. Here is a slightly changed demo to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/6ydR3/

Also, make sure to list the unprefixed version last.

Mixing percentages with other value types in the calc() function within a transform doesn't seem to work at all in Chrome. I'll report this as a bug.

UPDATE: This has been reported as a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150054

Comment: doesn't work in IE10 either :(. I guess it is not yet a suitable solution... thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/qdJwY/2/

(edit: Tested in Firefox only)

In your example it just so happens that `100% = 200px`, so you translated by zero.

Comment: No go in latest opera and chrome